# How to insert an inactive timestamp with Minad's TempEl package?

Tags: package, template

I want to insert an inactive date/timestamp in Org mode with Daniel Mendler's `TempEl` templating system. The same date and time inserted with `C-u C-u C-!` looks like this `[2023-02-20 Mon 19:11]`.

I tried different ways but did not achieve it. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: What I don't understand is: why a template? You have to type a name and then something to expand it. How is that superior to `C-u C-u C-!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reading of the docs is that `TempEl` can evaluate arbitrary forms during template expansion to put something like this in the template:

```
(format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M]")
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this and let you know.